# Python not uninstalling (Windows 10)

Tags: python, windows, uninstallation

I would like to uninstall a version of python and it says ‘uninstall was successful’ when I uninstall from control panel or settings, I have tried clicking change and then repair, then uninstall, but it never goes away from the apps list. When I delete paths to it in environment settings, they come back. Also deleting folders in appdata and programdata doesn't work, they just come back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I speculate that this could be the broken registry. 
try [Microsoft uninstall troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed) or

to uninstall or troubleshoot your python installation.  Also you can use any third party tools like Revo uninstaller